# Saving Form Data using Web API and AngularJS (select list)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, asp.net-web-api

I have a form that displays personnel data and offers the ability to update the personnel information and save the changes to my database. See form below:

[image: Figure 1. Personnel Information Form]

The fields that are bound to the textboxes I have no issues updating. Though, when it comes to the HTML select list (dropdown), I'm unable to save the newly selected value.

*NOTE* I can make a change in any number of textboxes and then make a change to the selection in the select list and the rest of the form saves properly, just without the changes to the select list, so it doesn't appear to be failing anywhere.

I'm not receiving any errors; however, I am seeing an additional OPTIONS request before the PUT, which I'm unsure about (so any additional tips on why that is would also be appreciated).

Here's my form:

```
<form name="personForm" novalidate ng-controller="PersonnelEditCtrl as vm">
<fieldset class="col-md-4">
    <legend>Basic Personnel Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group row" ng-class="{'has-error':personForm.inputLastName.$invalid && personForm.inputLastName.$dirty}">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputLastName" name="inputLastName" 
                   type="text" placeholder="Last Name (required)" 
                   ng-model="vm.person.lastName" required ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="30" />
        </div>
        <span class="help-block" has-error">
            <span ng-show="personForm.inputLastName.$error.required">
                Last name is required.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="person.form.inputLastName.$error.minlength">
                Last name must be at least 1 character in length.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="person.form.inputLastName.$error.maxlength">
                Last name cannot exceed 30 characters in length.
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" ng-class="{'has-error':personForm.inputFirstName.$invalid && personForm.inputFirstName.$dirty}">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="inputFirstName" 
                   type="text" placeholder="First Name (required)" 
                   ng-model="vm.person.firstName" required ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="30" />
        </div>
        <span class="help-block" has-error">
            <span ng-show="personForm.inputFirstName.$error.required">
                First name is required.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="person.form.inputFirstName.$error.minlength">
                First name must be at least 1 character in length.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="person.form.inputFirstName.$error.maxlength">
                First name cannot exceed 30 characters in length.
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" ng-class="{'has-error':personForm.inputMiddleInitial.$invalid && personForm.inputMiddleInitial.$dirty}">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputMiddleInitial">Middle Initial</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputMiddleInitial" name="inputMiddleInitial" 
                   type="text" placeholder="Middle Initial (required)" 
                   ng-model="vm.person.middleInitial" required ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="1" />
        </div>
        <span class="help-block" has-error">
            <span ng-show="personForm.inputMiddleInitial.$error.required">
                Middle initial is required.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="person.form.inputMiddleInitial.$error.minlength">
                Middle initial must be at least 1 character in length.
            </span>
            <span ng-show="person.form.inputMiddleInitial.$error.maxlength">
                Middle initial cannot exceed 1 characters in length.
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="vm.person.dob" type="date" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectPayband">Payband</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <select id="selectPayband" name="selectPayband" 
                    ng-model="vm.person.payband" ng-options="payband.name for payband in vm.paybands track by payband.id">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:80px; margin-right:10px" 
                        ng-click="vm.submit()" ng-disabled="personForm.$invalid">Save</button>
            </span>
            <span>
                <button class="btn btn-default" style="width:70px" 
                        ng-click="vm.cancel(personForm)">Cancel</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" ng-show="vm.message">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <pre style="font: inherit">{{ vm.message }}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

personnelEditCtrl.js

```
angular
.module("personnelService")
.controller("PersonnelEditCtrl",
             PersonnelEditCtrl);

function PersonnelEditCtrl(personnelResource, paybandResource, $filter) {
var vm = this;
vm.person = {};
vm.message = '';
vm.paybands = [];

paybandResource.query(function (data) {
    vm.paybands = $filter('orderBy')(data, 'Name');
});

personnelResource.get({ id: 2 },
    function (data) {
        vm.person = data;
        vm.person.dob = new Date(vm.person.dob);
        vm.originalPerson = angular.copy(data);
    });

if (vm.person && vm.person.personId) {
    vm.title = "Edit: " + vm.person.firstName + " " + vm.person.lastName;
}
else {
    vm.title = "New Person";
}

vm.submit = function () {
    vm.message = '';
    if (vm.person.personId) {
        vm.person.$update({ id: vm.person.personId },
            function (data) {
                vm.message = '... Save Complete';
            })
    }
    else {
        vm.person.$save(
            function (data) {
                vm.originalPerson = angular.copy(data);
                vm.message = '... Save Complete';
            })
    }
};

vm.cancel = function (editForm) {
    editForm.$setPristine();
    vm.person = angular.copy(vm.originalPerson);
    vm.message = "";
};
}
```

personnelResource.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("personnelResource",
            ["$resource",
             "appSettings",
                personnelResource])

function personnelResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/people/:id", null,
        {
            'update':{method:'PUT'}
        });
}
}());
```

paybandResource.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("paybandResource",
            ["$resource",
             "appSettings",
                paybandResource])

function paybandResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/paybands/:id");
}
}());
```

Database Structure:

**dbo.People**

```
PersonId : int (PK)
FirstName : string
MiddleInitial: string
LastName : string
DateOfBirth: datetime
PaybandId : int (FK)
```

**dbo.Paybands**

```
Id : int (PK)
Name : string
```

It probably has nothing to do with it, but I'll post my Web API Controller code for "People" as well:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using CPS.WebAPI.Models;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CPS.WebAPI.Controllers
{
[EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:53265", "*", "*")]
public class PeopleController : ApiController
{
    private CPS_Context db = new CPS_Context();

    public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return db.Person;
    }

    public Person Get(int id)
    {
        Person person;

        if (id > 0)
        {
            var people = db.Person;
            person = people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonId == id);
        }
        else
        {
            person = db.Person.Create();
        }

        return person;
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]Person person)
    {
        CPS_Context db = new CPS_Context();
        var newPerson = db.Person.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Person person)
    {
        CPS_Context db = new CPS_Context();
        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        var updatedPerson = db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Don't mind the bare minimum code for the Web API, I'm just doing everything from scratch and doing everything as minimal as possible to get it working in the mean time.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide in helping me to save the selected option in my select list. Please let me know if you have any further questions or need any more information - I tried to be as thorough as possible. Thanks again in advance for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: have you tried ng-change on the select passing the ng-model and see if it changed there?

Comment: I haven't - I'm still getting the hang of Angular. I'll look into that directive now. Thanks

Comment: So yeah, I got ng-update to work (just pushed the selected value to an array and displayed it). So I'm not sure why this doesn't want to save the newly selected value in the select list, but it'll save everything else if it's in a textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not saving the the select value? Does the select value actually get set? Why are you doing this `{{ vm.person.payband = payband.id}}` inside the select?

Comment: @user2718281 - So let me try to clarify: when I load the page, the correct value for the Payband that is currently stored in the database is loaded and pre-selected in the select list. So if I want to change this value from what's seen in the screenshot above ("WS"), and choose a new value and try to save it, it doesn't save. But say I change any of the textbox values and then try to save the form... only the textbox values update in the database, but not the value in the select list. I cannot change this Payband value no matter what and that's what I need help on: getting it to save.

Comment: @user2718281 - {{ vm.person.payband = payband.id }} inside the select was a typo - updated the original post with the fix in HTML.

Comment: Looks like `person.payband` should be the payband id so shouldn't the select `ngOptions` be `ng-options="payband.id as payband.name for payband in vm.paybands"`. Also, try putting `{{vm.person.payband}}` some where in your template, change the select and check the value is what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My issue turned out to be that JSON data included Navigation Properties. The update failed because there was a referential integrity conflict.

The solution to my problem was to update my Entity Framework data model to exclude navigation properties from JSON. I did this by adding [JsonIgnore] attribute like this:

```
[ForeignKey("Payband")]
public virtual int PaybandId { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Payband Payband { get; set; }
```